# when running npm run build on lunix it's not working

Tags: vue.js, npm

when running : npm run build on lunix server i got :
Error: Cannot find module :

'/usr/home/html/production/libs/laravel/app_inventory_v2/front/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-router/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:353:19)
at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:566:18)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
at idToPlugin (/usr/home/html/production/libs/laravel/app_inventory_v2/front/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:145:14)
at /usr/home/html/production/libs/laravel/app_inventory_v2/front/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:184:20
at Array.map ()
at Service.resolvePlugins (/usr/home/html/production/libs/laravel/app_inventory_v2/front/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:170:10) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
path: '/usr/home/html/production/libs/laravel/app_inventory_v2/front/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-router/package.json',
requestPath: '@vue/cli-plugin-router'

Answer (score 1):

Several things that might be checked:

1. Verify you don't include the `node_modules` directory from your development host. It may contain binaries that are only meant for specific platforms.
2. Perform a clean installation by running the `npm ci` command on your production host. Verify you have stored `package.json` and `package-lock.json` on the server.